# How can a computer on an external network access my iis website

Tags: iis, deployment

My IIS website works fine on my computer and anything on the same ip address but when I try accessing myip:myport/api/ it times out. I already went into my windows firewall and set up an inbound rule:
[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcSEM.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcSEM.png)

Not sure what the issue is at this point, any help appreciated.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/self-hosting-series-why-cannot-my-web-server-iis-be-reached-from-anywhere-else-8da0e0b252ef

Comment: I suggest you try to ping your computer with machine that accesses myip to check if it can get reply.  
If the timeout is not caused by firewall interception, it is most likely a network problem. The computer where your site is located should be your personal computer, personal computer cannot be pinged under public network conditions. You need to place the device in the same LAN.Or you need a public ip so that can access site through public network.